# Which browsers running css animations apart from javascript thread?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I'm targeting this questions to browsers with versions same or above:

- IE 11
- Chorme 69
- Firefox 62

I have simple css animation which runs fine on all of above browsers:

```
span.loader {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-indent: -12345px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0, 0.08);
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0, 0.08);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0, 0.08);
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: spinner 700ms infinite linear;
    z-index: 100001;
}
@keyframes spinner {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

When I run this animation and execute some expensive javascript code animation stops in IE11 but not in Chrome or Firefox.

Does it mean that FF and Chrome are running css animations in separate thread apart form javascript thread and IE does not? Am I missing something?

IT Man

Comment: For the animation you are using, the so called modern browsers will run it in a separate thread http://www.phpied.com/css-animations-off-the-ui-thread/

Comment: IE11 is considered to be modern? I'm asking because in my case it stops css animation while javascript is running.

Comment: Heres the test page https://output.jsbin.com/riyavedese/

Comment: @ITMan was there any solution for this? I can see this thread just ended here. I am facing a similar issue and would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: @AkashPal Nothing new here. I can confirm that IE stops animation when expensive javascript operation is running.

Comment: @ITMan so did you find a workaround to optimize this. or can you suggest how to approach this ?

Comment: @AkashPal no, I'm "living with that" actually my clients are. I'm my apps this is not significant feature.